# Efficient current drive with arbitrary waveform

Tags: current-source, class-d

I need to drive a defined, arbitrary current waveform into an output with a load impedance that may not be constant.

Currently, I am using this:

[image]

The 100V is created from 9V dc using a standard boost converter circuit. Peak current is 0.2 A.

Questions:

- Is there a more energy efficient design that avoids dropping all that voltage in the transistor that does not break the bank from a component count standpoint? Is there a clever way to merge the current control with the DC-DC voltage boost circuit? (I am thinking class D amplifier or transformerless [Cuk converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%86uk_converter).)
- What would be a good design/approach if the output had to be galvanically isolated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have there controls the output current into the load.

You could replace the fixed 100 V supply with a variable voltage boost converter. This would be controlled by sensing the collector voltage on your transistor, driving it to (say) 5 V.

You would choose the threshold voltage appropriately. A lower voltage means better efficinecy. A higher voltage gives you more headroom to cope with any rapid changes of the load impedance, or allows you to have a slower responding power supply.

Comment: Thanks. But how will this cope with fluctuating impedance? Lets the load rapidly goed from high to low impedance. Then the capacitor was previously charge to a high voltage to drive a given current. If the impedance drops, this voltage leads to a rise in the current through my load as the voltage is still on the capacitor. Only once it is discharge can the current sensing down-regulate the voltage. It seems to me that the fidelity could be extremely poor with this approach.

Comment: The existing current control you have needs to have the bandwidth to control the load current against load impedance changes, whether you use a fixed 100 V supply, or have a slowly changing supply voltage. All the supply voltage modulation does is minimise the collector voltage, subject to the constraint that it doesn't get too low, the thresholds are up to you. Andy suggests measuring the collector voltage with an ADC, and programming the supply. This is potentially slower than using a linear feedback scheme, but potentially smarter if you know something interesting about the load dynamics.

Comment: Thanks. I obviously misunderstood your answer. If I understand correctly, you were not proposing to get rid of the current control with the transistor entirely and only modulating the voltage but to lower the voltage headroom that causes the majority of the energy loss. - Am I on the right track now? That sounds like a very practical approach... Thanks.

Comment: Yes. My answer isn't completely clear. I say replace the 100 V supply, without explcicityl saying keep the current control, but I do say control the supply voltage by using the voltage on the collector of your transistor, which means keep your transistor.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how accurate and ripple-free you want the load current to be.

If you want low ripple and fast response time then what you have drawn will be the only solution without compromising performance. If you have an isolated 100 volt supply you could always feed the MCU PWM signal via an opto or a magnetic isolation chip such as the [ADuM540x](https://www.analog.com/en/products/adum5401.html): -

[image]

Then power your op-amp by stealing some power from \$V_{ISO}\$. But you'd still need to generate an isolated 100 volt supply. Assuming you are able to do this, you could monitor the standing DC voltage at the collector via an ADC (on the isolated side) and use the spare digital isolation channels to talk with this ADC, acquire the voltage on the collector and adjust the 100 volts down to some more reasonable value that saves blowing the lid off the BJT as it gets too warm when \$R_{LOAD}\$ is low in value.

Comment: Thanks for reassuring me that the energy inefficiency may not be avoidable. Also many thanks for the advice on the isolation problem.